# can't find CBF tool for PROGRESS Database

Tags: .net, progress

I want to connect .net application with PROGRESS DB.
I think, I will need Component Builder Framework(CBF) which is debugging tool for progress, but unable 2 find it anywhere.

Anybody aware whether its license has been taken back or something?
Because I know it was there 2 years back.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want direct access to the Progress DB, then you could use ODBC. If you have an appserver in place for your business logic, then you have a bunch of other options via the Open Client Interface or webservices. Have never come across this CBF.

Progress docs - http://communities.progress.com/pcom/docs/DOC-16074.

Comment: No. I don't want direct access to Progress DB. I want my Business logic in c# .Net application, not on progress appserver. I am trying
to make an interface using progress debugging tool which will create .cs file. since earlier progress is now revised to ABL(Advance business Language), don't have any idea of its current debugging tools. I heard CBF was a debugging tool for old progress. Please tell me if I am wrong. I found OpenEdge Editor Can it be used?

Comment: Ah, other way around - you want to call your .NET BL from an ABL routine. You confused me by mentioning the Progress DB. As I said, I've never come across this CBF, but you have some options for what you want. For example, you could expose your c# routines as a webservice and call that from the ABL. 

Check out the "Integration and General Business Interfaces" manuals in that link above.

Comment: There are currently license limitations on doing this (calling C# from ABL), but there is an effort to reduce/remove these. See   http://communities.progress.com/pcom/thread/26605?tstart=0 for more.